# Vowel sound in *die* vs *dice*

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, vowels

Is it just me, or is the letter "i" pronounced differently in the words *die* and *dice*?  In *die*, it sounds like the regular long I sound (ay), but in the word *dice*, it sounds closer to something like "əy" with a short schwa sound.

Comment: It's just you..

Comment: @HotLicks Aw, don't tease the poor fellow. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You’re right: one is [aɪ] but the other one, which is shorter and higher, is [ʌɪ].

This phenomenon is called, dubiously at best, [*Canadian raising*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canadian_raising). Most North Americans do this with that diphthong. Wikipedia writes:

> Raising of just /aɪ/ is found throughout the United States, and so may be considered an increasingly common General American characteristic, with the only major exception in the U.S. being in the South.

It happens mostly before voiceless consonants, of which the /s/ at the end of *dice* is one. That makes *dice* come out as [dʌɪs] but *die* is just the unraised [daɪ]. Other pairs are *tight/tide, writer/rider*, and the two versions of *high school*.

Comment: Yes, I was also thinking of high school and *high* school.  And this is especially confusing because these differences are not in the dictionary pronunciations.